# Vspace is applied to all three images

Tags: html

I was learning about this attribute vspace but it is applied to all three images which I have
I don't understand why?
As you can see in the code I have written only one vspace attribute in one of img tag. But It is moving all three images down vertically. Don't understand why?

[Screenshot of output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tVTwt.png)

**Code**

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <br> Can you see the stars
        <img src=stars.jpg height=200 width=200 >
        <img src=stars.jpg height=200 width=200>
        <img src=stars.jpg height=200 width=200 vspace=20 >
        Can you see the stars?
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your html is using a very old style. Using height, width, vspace attributes are old and not recommended. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/vspace

Comment: In fact, vspace is [obsolete](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/obsolete.html#non-conforming-features) and has been for at least a decade. Do not use vspace.